# DCAT RDF Harvesting errors

Tags: ckan, harvest, data-harvest, dcat

I tried DCAT RDF Harvesting at ckan. General ckan harvesting works well, but DCAT RDF Harvesting does not seem to add many configuratin feature. How can I resolve this error and get data from https://www.europeandataportal.eu ??

> Received harvest job id: 2ec257d4-6e29-4cc5-8e76-1ac4023b1d65
>   [ckanext.dcat.harvesters.rdf] In DCATRDFHarvester gather_stage
>   [ckanext.dcat.harvesters.base] Getting file
>   https://www.europeandataportal.eu [ckanext.harvest.model] The
>   validation service returned an error: 503 [ckanext.harvest.queue] No
>   harvest objects to fetch

I add this configuration in rdf.py and swden_dcat_harvest in my ckan configuration file.

> parser = RDFParser(profiles=['euro_dcat_ap', 'sweden_dcat_ap'])
>   serializer = RDFSerializer(profiles=['euro_dcat_ap',
>   'sweden_dcat_ap'])